# Gradient for arrow shape in IE-9

Tags: css, internet-explorer, for-loop, gradient

we are showing selected row of table in the form of arrow and want to apply a gradient to entire shape so we used below css

```
    .SelectedArea
    {
    z-index: 0;
    max-height: 35px;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#f4c471, #f9edca) !important; /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#f4c471, #f9edca) !important; /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#f4c471, #f9edca) !important; /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
    background: linear-gradient(#f4c471, #f9edca) !important; /* Standard syntax */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#f4c471', endColorstr='#f9edca',GradientType=0 );  
    }

    .SelectedArea:after
    {
         position: relative;
         float: right;
         top: 0;          
         width: 27px;
         height: 27px;
         transform: rotate(45deg);
         -ms-transform: rotate(45deg); /* IE 9 */
         -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg); /* Opera, Chrome, and Safari */

         background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #f4c471 , #f9edca); /* Standard syntax */
         content: '';
        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='red', endColorstr='#f9edca', GradientType=1);
        display: inline-block; 
    }
```

css in selected area class is working but gradient is not coming to arrow shape in IE.
is there any way I can give side property in filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient() I think that is the issue

Comment: if so it actually does not really relate to the arrow here, try create a simple demo with a `div` and try applying a gradient background to that `div` tested on IE9. Maybe it's because you don't know how to set the gradient direction using DXImageTransform, (it should be `to bottom right`), search for it, I guess there will be some answer out  there.

Comment: i tried but havent found a way to set to bottom right to DXImageTransform

Comment: Gradient is NOT supported in IE9. You have to use a SVG instead.

Comment: it is working for button,even first part of the arrow when i added filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='red', endColorstr='#f9edca', GradientType=1); it is only not working for arrow pointer

Comment: @user3615869 the bad news for you is Gradient is supported in IE9 **but** it supports only 2 directions: horizontal and vertical (determined by the `GradientType`). Sorry, you have to use another way to shape your arrow, in which we can just use vertical or horizontal gradient.